# Multiply (or divide) every n indexes of a DataFrame by an constant from array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame and I will like to multiply (or divide) every n indexes by a specific number from an array. A brief example is the following, where the letters are just numbers.

df =

```
   0  1
0  A  B
1  C  D
2  E  F
3  G  H
4  I  J
5  K  L
6  M  N
7  O  P
```

DataFrame (or numpy array):

```
   0  1
0  W  X
1  Y  Z
```

I will like to obtain the following result:

Result =

```
   0     1
0  A/W  B/X
1  C/Y  D/Z
2  E/W  F/X
3  G/Y  H/Z
4  I/W  J/X
5  K/Y  L/Z
6  M/W  N/X
7  O/Y  P/Z
```

Is it any way to solve this using `df.groupy(df % 2).agg()` or `df.groupy(df % 2).apply()` ? I am handling a huge DataFrame and I believe if I apply a for loop will take more time than needed.

I know I have to use a function, but I cannot code one that does what I am looking for.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

Start with defining a function to be applied to each group:

```
def dv(tbl):
    return tbl.divide(df2.values, axis='columns')
```

`df2` is converted to the underlying `values` in order to "free"
oneself from index alignment.

Then we read the number of rows in *df2* (the size of a group
in grouping of *df*):

```
len2 = len(df2.index)
```

Then the actual division can be performed with a single instruction:

```
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index)) // len2).apply(dv)
```

`np.arange(len(df.index)) // len2` provides division of `df` into
groups containing the same number of rows as `df2`.

To each group there is applied `dv` function (defined above).

For the test purpose I created the first DataFrame (*df*) as:

```
      0     1
0  10.0  11.0
1  12.0  13.0
2  14.0  15.0
3  16.0  17.0
4  18.0  19.0
5  20.0  21.0
6  22.0  23.0
7  24.0  25.0
```

and the second (*df2*) as:

```
     0    1
0  2.0  2.5
1  3.0  3.5
```

The result was:

```
           0         1
0   5.000000  4.400000
1   4.000000  3.714286
2   7.000000  6.000000
3   5.333333  4.857143
4   9.000000  7.600000
5   6.666667  6.000000
6  11.000000  9.200000
7   8.000000  7.142857
```

Of couse, the above code was for division.

If you want to multiply, then define a function:

```
def ml(tbl):
    return tbl.multiply(df2.values, axis='columns')
```

and apply it calling:

```
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index)) // len2).apply(ml)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick without requiring a loop or using apply:

```
df.iloc[::2, 0] = df.iloc[::2, 0] / df2.iloc[0, 0]
df.iloc[1::2, 0] = df.iloc[1::2, 0] / df2.iloc[0, 1]
df.iloc[::2, 1] = df.iloc[::2, 1] / df2.iloc[1, 0]
df.iloc[1::2, 1] = df.iloc[1::2, 1] / df2.iloc[1, 1]
```

This may also work, and could be used with any number of columns:

```
df.iloc[::2, :] = df.iloc[::2, :] / df2.iloc[0, :]
df.iloc[1::2, :] = df.iloc[1::2, :] / df2.iloc[1, :]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the index of the first dataframe as follows:

`df.index = df.index % 2`

Then merge on index:

```
df = df.join(df2, lsuffix='_l', rsuffix = '_r')
```

Then you want will be something like this

```
df['ratio1'] = df['0_l'] / df['0_r']
df['ratio2'] = df['1_l'] / df['1_r']
```

To get the exact form of your answer:

```
column_map = {'ratio1': 0, 'ratio2': 1}
df = df[['ratio1', 'ratio2']].rename(columns= column_map)
```